# bash : If branch for two different loop

Tags: bash

I am writing a for loop. But the loop is dependent on the content of positional argument.

- If the positional arguments are `seq 2 1 10`, the loop is `for i in $(seq 2 1 10)`
- If the positional arguments are purely numbers such as `1 2 5 7 10`, then the loop is `for i in 1 2 5 7 10`.

I tried this, but it didn't work:

```
test () {
if [[ $1 == seq ]]
then
for i in $(seq $2 $3 $4)
else
for i in $@
fi
do
echo $i
done
}
```

I also tried this:

```
test2 () {
if [[ $1 == seq ]]
then
sss="for i in $(seq $2 $3 $4)"
else
sss="for i in $@"
fi
$sss
do
echo $i
done
}
```

also doesn't work.

So my questions are:

1. I know I could write explicit two loop inside if. But if loop content is large, this is a waste of code space. Is there any better way?
2. In my second attempt, why doesn't `$sss` expand to a `for` sentence and get parsed properly by bash?

Comment: `test` is not the best name for a function as it clashes with the shell builtin `test`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the list of numbers in an array.

```
test () {
    if [[ $1 == seq ]]
    then
        numbers=($(seq "$2" "$3" "$4"))
    else
        numbers=("$@")
    fi

    for i in "${numbers[@]}"
    do
        echo $i
    done
}
```

> In my second attempt, why doesn't `$sss` expand to a `for` sentence and get parsed properly by bash?

A variable can be expanded into a command to run, but not into a flow control construct like a `for` loop or `if` statement. Those need to be written out directly, they can't be stored in variables. If you try, bash will attempt to run a command named `for`--that is, it will look in `/bin`, `/usr/bin`, etc., for a binary named `for`.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using arrays as in [John Kugelman](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45910562/900873)'s answer is to use `set --` to change the positional parameters:

```
test () 
{ 
    if [[ $1 == seq ]]; then
        set -- $(seq $2 $3 $4)
    fi
    for i; do
        echo $i
    done
}
```

Note that `for i` is equivalent to `for i in "$@"`.

John already mentioned why it didn't work - variable interpolation and splitting happens after control flow is parsed.

Comment: Thank you so much for introduce `set  --`